# Inductance and speed of light

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, inductance, magnetostatics

I am studying mutual inductance (or self-inductance), and some clear answer is ignored, not asked or answered in any source i am looking for.

If current is changing then equations of static electromagnetism (like ampere's law) shouldn't be true anymore. It takes time for waves to propagate. We are no longer dealing with with a static situation.

I would like to follow a fully logical path while studying. Is there any sources that study this subject by fully considering all aspects of non static electromagnetism?

Comment: I think your question is based on a misunderstanding. Ampere’s law is not static. All of Maxwell’s equations are valid in electrodynamic scenarios

Comment: Virtually every electromagnetism textbook handles electrodynamics. They just start with electrostatics for simplicity. Flip a couple chapters later in your book, to the one that uses the full Ampere’s and Faraday’s laws (including the derivatives).

Comment: @Dale so your saying if current in a wire 100km away from you but stationary to you changes, then the magnetic field near you instantly changes?

Comment: @Gilbert no you are wrong. the reason for asking this is because i have never found any resource even discussing the matter i'm looking for. it's not about studying it in a book, it's about studying it anywhere i can find. i want the effects of speed of light in a inductor

Comment: Nowhere did I say that. Please don’t misquote me or put words in my mouth. You appear to misunderstand Ampere’s law if you believe that what I did say implies what you said

Comment: If you specifically want the answer to a question about the speed of light in an inductor, then you should ask that specific question directly. The way your question is worded you are asking for a resource recommendation for studying electrodynamics.

Comment: @TheNegative then you haven't looked at any electrodynamics textbook at great length, even the undergrad level Griffiths approaches the finite speed of light and electrodynamics using maxwell's equations. He even derives the Liénard–Wiechert potentials https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential

Comment: @TheNegative: The way this works is that we have Maxwell's Equations, which appropriately includes the speed of light, and then you have many equations, laws, etc, that deal with simplified situations. The simplified situations are very important to gain a full understanding, and are a good start. It's impossible to do what it seems you're hoping for, which is to just learn the fullest/truest understanding of everything from the ground up. But if you want to try, any source that gives a good treatment of Maxwell's equations is a good start on the full picture, and there are many such sources.

Comment: @TheNegative I suppose I’m unclear on your question, then. Perhaps you could edit your question to be more explicit? As it is, your final sentence implies that you’re just looking for an electrodynamics text.